# Get next tracks from queue through Spotify App API

Tags: javascript, spotify, spotify-queue

Is there anyway to get the next tracks from the player queue?

I get the current track using:

```
var player = models.player;
var playerTrackInfo = player.track;
```

But I can't find the way to get the context, or the next track.

Answer (score 2):

The API doesn't support reading the next-playing track. The `Player` model does let you skip to the next track though: https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-player.html

A workaround could be to construct a temporary playlist and then inspect the next track programmatically.